# Change <P> Tag to <DIV> Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

A caption is displayed under the picture.
But it `<p>` tag but i am need `<div>`

> change `<p class="wp-caption-text">` to `<div class="wp-caption-text">`

Example :

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">any-content<p>
```

I need :

```
<div class="wp-caption-text">any-content<div>
```

---

Variant with shortcode and jquery are not needed and not suited.

I tried to do it through:

```
function filter_ptags_on_capt($content)
{
    return preg_replace("/(<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">.*<\/p>)/Us", "<div class=\"wp-caption-text\">$1</div>",$content); ?>
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_capt');
```

But it not work.
Maybe I wrote the regular expression wrong, but maybe it does not work that way.

Comment: the function doesn't return anything. Put `return` in front of the preg_replace

Comment: and right now you put the `<p>` _inside_ the div (because the `()` in the regex capture the whole phraze to be put into $1). Move those `()` to wrap only `(.*)`

Comment: `return preg_replace("/<p class=\"wp-caption-text\">(.*)<\/p>/Us", "<div class=\"wp-caption-text\">$1</div>",$content)`;

right? but not work, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A slight change in your preg_match function. Please try the below it was working for me.

Change

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">any-content<p>
```

to

```
<div class="wp-caption-text">any-content<div>
```

Code:

```
function filter_ptags_on_capt($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p class="wp-caption-text">(.*?)<p>/', '<div class="wp-caption-text">$1<div>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_capt');
```

If you want to change

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">any-content</p>
```

to

```
<div class="wp-caption-text">any-content</div>
```

then try the below code.

Code:

```
function filter_ptags_on_capt($content)
{
    return preg_replace('/<p class="wp-caption-text">(.*?)<\/p>/', '<div class="wp-caption-text">$1</div>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_capt');
```

I think the second one would be the perfect html format with proper close HTML tag.

Thanks.

Comment: sorry, but no changes ;(

Comment: I have tried the raw php code for the above HTML element.


`$content = '<p class="wp-caption-text">any-content</p>';

echo preg_replace('/<p class="wp-caption-text">(.*?)<\/p>/', '<div class="wp-caption-text">$1</div>', $content);`

You please try this http://phpfiddle.org/

Answer (score 0):

This work code

```
function filter_wp_caption_div( $content ) {
    return preg_replace(
        '/<p[^>]+class="wp-caption-text"[^>]*>(.+)(?=<\/p>)/s',
        '<div class="wp-caption-text">\1</div>',
        $content
    );
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_wp_caption_div', 12 );
```